# How to update AppDBContext in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am quite new to ASP.NET and I am bit stuck with this.
I am creating an entry in my DB while registering the user:

```
private async Task<bool> CreateEntryInUserActions(AppUser user)
        {
                var entity = new UserActionEntity
                {
                    UserId = user.Id,
                };

                await _context.tbl_UserActions.AddAsync(entity);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return true;
         }
```

I want to change the IsPasswordChanged field in the UserActions table to true when a user changes his/her password.
I am trying something like:

```
private async Task<bool> UpdateUserAction()
        {
            var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value; // gives me current user's id

            var user = _context.tbl_UserActions
                .Where(x => x.UserId.ToString() == userId).Select(x => x.IsPasswordChanged);

        }
```

but I am not sure how to proceed and update this to "true". How do I update this entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the useraction entity from the table and then set the IsPasswordChanged property to true.

Try this:

```
private async Task<bool> UpdateUserAction()
    {
        var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value; // gives me current user's id

        var user = _context.tbl_UserActions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId.ToString() == userId);
        if(user != null) //check if the record is not null
        {
            user.IsPasswordChanged = true; // set the column to desired value
            _context.tbl_UserActions.Update(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
         }

    }
```

Comment: Oh I see. I though I had to query over the user and then use some pre-defined method to update the field. But this worked nicely. Thank you! :)